# Using something else instead of String

Tags: java, string, arrays

I have a big file and I want to do some „operations” on it.(find some text, check if some text exists, get the offset of some text, maybe changing the file).

My current aproach is this:

```
public ResultSet getResultSet(String fileName) throws IOException {

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[CAPACITY];
    byte[] doubleBuffer = new byte[2 * CAPACITY];


    long len = in.read(doubleBuffer);
    while (true) {
        String reconstitutedString = new String(doubleBuffer, 0 ,doubleBuffer.length);

        //...do stuff

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        os.write(doubleBuffer, CAPACITY, CAPACITY);
        readUntilNow += len;
        len = in.read(buffer);
        if (len <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        os.write(buffer, 0, CAPACITY);
        doubleBuffer = os.toByteArray();
        os.close();
    }
    in.close();
    return makeResult();

}
```

I would like to change the **String reconstitutedString** into something else. What would be the best alternative considering I want to be able to get some information about the content of that data, information that I may get calling an IndexOf on a String

Comment: Since those are methods of the class String, what makes you assume there is an alternative? You can use StringBuilder to build it, but you'll still need the String value to perform those actions. Unless of course you are willing to create your own implementation and re-write all those methods.

Comment: Well, I don't seek an alternative with the same exact methods. As long as I have a way of getting the same result as an indexOf, I am pleased.

Comment: I was only mentioning the methods you stated you would need. They are very specific to String objects, so you won't really find them in another class, unless you were to create it.

Comment: Maybe i should have explained myself in another way regarding those methods. English isn't my first language and sometimes I have problems explaining what i really want. Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it.

Comment: @CristianMarian How huge is "huge"? Does your code work or not? Is it slow? If not, what is your question?

Comment: My file is 20-30 KB. And the code works. My question is if i can use something else instead of String to improve the memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` . This two class has almost like  `String` class with the advantage of mutability.

Moreover you can easily convert them to `String` whenever you required some functionality that only `String` provides. To convert them you can just use the `toString()` method.

You may use some other data type as an alternative to `String` based on your situation. But in general  `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` is the best alternative instead of string. Use `StringBuffer` for synchronization and `StringBuilder` in other case.

Comment: Can you `split` on them? No, you can't.

Comment: Tichodroma: of course not, but you can get the String from them, and split on that.

Comment: @Stultuske What would be the use? If the OP doesn't want to use `String`, getting one from a `StringBuffer` is no solution. BTW, I still don't understand what the problem is. Why does the OP want to avoid `String` in the first place?

Comment: @Tichodroma: what would be the use of "not using a String, but want to have all the functionalities of String" ?
Don't get me wrong, I totally agree with you. Just pointing out the option, that's all.

Comment: @Tichodroma: yes you can [`split` a `StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Answer (score 0):

The best type to do `split` or `indexOf` on is `String`. Just use it.

Comment: I have really **huge** files. And I really want to get rid of  `String`. And as I stated in another comment, I need a way to get the same result as an indexOf, not really interested in being able to call indexOf on my alternative.

Comment: Then you should go with `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` and easily convert them to `String` with `toString()` method when you need some only `String` specific operation. It's proven that `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` is much faster than `String`

Answer (score 0):

The most natural choice would be [`CharBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html). Like `String` and `StringBuilder` it implements the `CharSequence` `interface`, therefore it can be used with a lot of text oriented APIs, most notably the [regex engine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher(java.lang.CharSequence)) which is the back-end for most search, split, and replacing operations.

What makes `CharBuffer` the natural choice is that it is also the type that is used by the [charset package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/package-summary.html) which provides the necessary operations for converting characters from and to bytes. By dealing with this API you can do the conversion directly from and to `CharBuffer`s without additional data copying steps.

Note that Java’s regex API is prepared for processing buffers containing partially read files and can report whether reading more data might change the result (see [`hitEnd()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#hitEnd()) and [`requireEnd()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#requireEnd())).

These are the necessary tools for building applications which can process large files in smaller chunks and without creating `String` instance out of it (or only when necessary, e.g. when extracting a matching subsequence).